# wp7 record filtering

Tags: windows-phone-7, filtering

For a Windows Phone 7 app, I have several Customer records that I need to display based on when the customers where created, so something like a start date and end date filter (maybe some canned entries listbox that lets you pick - tomorrow, week, month, custom)

Any UI guidance of how to do this so that the interface is kept clean and still leaves enough space for the records to get displayed?

Thanks,
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

You could reserve the majority of the display space for your data and show a brief indication of the current filter in place.

This filter could be an active control of your choice that when tapped takes the user to another page where you provide the criteria selection.

Initially it could show "No filter (tap for criteria)" or some such.

Comment: Mick, that is a good idea. Do you know of a sample that demonstrates this approach. I will be able to re-use some xaml (still learning).

Comment: Not at the moment, it's likely a good exercise to learn with though. Start with the navigation between the two pages and build on that .. you might have some more questions as you go. Here's a link to get started on that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626521(v=VS.92).aspx